# Using Ifelse Condition Without Using Else

Tags: r, flextable

I have a Flextable `df` and the following condition:

```
df = setFlexTableBackgroundColors(df, i = 1, j = 5:15,
colors = ifelse(test$object == 0,"white"))
```

However it gives me the following error message:

```
Error in ifelse(test$object == 0, "white") :
argument "no" is missing, with no default"
```

Apparently the package wants something like this: `ifelse(test$object == 0, "white", "black")`, because then the condition is working.

However I am using this condition on different rows that have different colors (j = 5:15) and I don't want them to turn `"black"` if the condition is not fulfilled.

Does someone have any hints how I can solve this problem?

Comment: This is not related to that package. You simply haven't understood how `ifelse` works. There must be an "else" value passed to it. Pass the current colors as the "else" value.

Comment: I understand how the ifelse future works. I am looking for something like, "Iflese( test==0 , white , if not do nothing and remain the same color )" that works with this Package.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the function with the default parameter it expects. In this particular case, you can do:

```
df = setFlexTableBackgroundColors(df, i = 1, j = 5:15,
  colors = ifelse(test$object == 0,"white","gray"))
```

In a more general case, the default value can be obtained with formals():

```
defaultColors = formals(setFlexTableBackgroundColors)$colors
df = setFlexTableBackgroundColors(df, i = 1, j = 5:15,
  colors = ifelse(test$object == 0,"white",defaultColors))
```

For instance:

```
ff <- function(x, y=5, z=7) {}
formals(ff)$y     # Returns 5
```

Comment: This is a good idea. Getting the format of the specific cell. However it does not work. I guess it is a feature that does not work with the peculiarities of the packe. I don't know if you have worked with the Package, but the command "format" needs to access a Flextable(x,i=5,j=5,colors=...). But thank you for the idea. I will work in this direction.